# Gitlab CI/Cd pipeline not working for iOS | Cocoapods not installed or in invalid state

Tags: ios, flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am doing CI/CD integration for my Flutter app. For Android, everything is working fine.
But for iOS, I am getting

`Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install. You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working. This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it. This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions. CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`

this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
stages:
 - build

build_project:
  stage: build
  only:
   - 75-setup-ci-cd-pipeline
  script:
   - flutter clean
   - flutter build ipa --flavor production -t lib/main_production.dart
   - flutter build appbundle --flavor production -t lib/main_production.dart
  tags:
   - flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using tags to choose which runner is doing your job 'build_project', so I assume that you already have a runner with the associated tag "flutter", otherwise the job would not have been started. But make sure that all the runner that can pick up this job have images that are compatible for iOS building.

I did not have setup such a pipeline, but I suggest you use the "before_script" field in your job to install/update the different packages before launching the different builds. The only pipeline that I have made is [here](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CICD/blob/master/doc_gitlab_cicd/.gitlab-ci.yml), and I used this "before_script" to install zip on the runner before running a script.

However, when I build for macos, I always run the following commands, maybe you can adapt them with iOS. These usually solve my problems with CocoaPods.

```
flutter clean
cd macos
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
cd ..
flutter pub get
cd macos
arch -x86_64 pod install
arch -x86_64 pod update
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
cd ..
flutter build macos --release
```